# Matplotlib not reading time axis correctly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, time

I want to visualise the **daily** data using `Matplotlib`. The data is temperature against time and has this format:

```
    Time    Temperature

1   8:23:04      18.5
2   8:23:04      19.0
3   9:12:57      19.0
4   9:12:57      20.0
... ... ...
```

But when plotting the graph, the `Time` values on `x-axis` is distorted, which looks like this:
[image]

Realising `Matplotlib` may not be interpreting time data correctly, I converted the time format using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format="%H:%M:%S")  

df.plot( 'Time', 'Temperature',figsize=(20, 10))

df.describe()
```

but this again returned:
[image]

How to make the time on `x-axis` look normal? Thanks

Comment: What is the output of `df.dtypes`?

Comment: @MichaelO.`Time:object; Temperature: float64; dtype: object`

Comment: And what gives `df.iloc[0, 0]`?

Comment: @MichaelO. It returned `'17:29:33'`.

Comment: So `Time` has the wrong format because it should return something like `Timestamp('1900-01-01 08:23:04')`. Also since you have 17 hours and 08 hours in time, it looks like your time column contains more than one day, so you should add year, month and day to data.

Comment: Hi @MichaelO. I just checked the the `Time` column and it seems all the data falls on the same day

Comment: Whatever the case, `Time` contains a string, not datetime. The error seems to be there.

Comment: @MichaelO. In Excel, `Time` has format `8:23:04 am`. Could that be considered as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Michael O. was saying, you need to take care of the datetime.
You miss the day, year and month.   Here I implemented a possible solution adding these missing data with some default values, you may want to change them.
The code is very simple and the comments illustrate what I am doing.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, date, time, timezone
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

vals=[["8:23:04",      18.5],
["8:23:04",      19.0],
["9:12:57",      19.0],
["9:12:57",      20.0]]
apd=pd.DataFrame(vals, columns=["Time", "Temp"])

# a simple function to convert a string to datetime
def conv_time(cell):
    dt = datetime.strptime(cell, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
    return(dt)


# the dataframe misses the day, month and year, we need to add some
apd["Time"]=["{}/{}/{} {}".format(1,1,2020, cell) for cell in apd["Time"]]

# we use the function to convert the column to a datetime
apd["Time"]=[conv_time(cell) for cell in apd["Time"]]

## plotting the results taking care of the axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H"))
ax.set_xlim([pd.to_datetime('2020-01-1 6:00:00'), pd.to_datetime('2020-01-1 12:00:00')])
ax.scatter(apd["Time"], apd["Temp"])
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. Is it possible to show the "`time`" data for the graph? Because I'm more interested in time than the date. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I did some changes but I don't really understand your comment.  I changed the axis in hour if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Yes. That's what I meant. I think it's working now. Thanks!